# How do I show that if it is a random walk or not? I don't know how to start?

Tags: probability, random-variables, martingales, mathematical-modeling, random-walk

Let $$Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, . . . .Y_i$$ be i.i.d. random variables. State with reason whether the below processes is a Random Walk.

$$X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$$

Comment: What's your definition of "random walk"?  But a hint: the random variables $Y_0^2, Y_1^2, \dots$ are also iid.

Comment: Definition of random walk is $$X_n = X_0 + Y_1 + Y_2 .... + Y_n$$ where each $$Y_i$$ are i.i.d. Hence if each Y are i.i.d then each $$ Y_i^2$$ should be i.i.d as well. Thus, it is a Random Walk. Right? What would a counter example be? Is $$Y_i Y_(i-1)$$ and $$Y_i -2$$ counter examples?

Comment: Right, this is indeed a random walk.  I'm not sure what you mean by your "counter examples".

Comment: Counter example as in what would not be a random walk processes? Like $$X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(Y_(i-1))$$ would not be a random walk processes because each $$Y_i$$ is dependent on the previous term? Right? And it would be the same for $$X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-2$$

Comment: Then this is indeed a random walk. Basically you are defining a random walk as a sum of iid random variables (but starting with any other random variable $X_0$ independent of all the $Y_i$). The first counterexample is correct, and the second one is not : $X_0 = -2$ and each $Y_i$ is iid, so $X_n$ as defined is a random walk, it is a shifted one.

Comment: Ah I get it. Thank you so much kind people! I'm struggling with Random Walks and Martingales due to the CoVid- 19 situation and its hard to learn online. If anyone has links or resources which explains further, do link it it please. Thank you so much once again for the help!  I really appreciated!